# When google-services.json file changed the code stopped working

Tags: firebase, flutter

My Code was running smoothly I am using firebase along with flutter. Today I tried to change the firebase project it was part of by changing the google-services.json file but suddenly the code stopped working. Weird thing is even a simple raised button is not working properly.
As an example, this should at least print entered to the console. Since I commented out everything else but even that's not happening.

```
RaisedButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 59,
                  right: 59,
                  top: 10,
                  bottom: 10,
                ),
                color: Colors.lightGreen[600],
                onPressed: () async {
                  print('entered');
                  // if (phoneNo == '') {
                  //   setState(() {
                  //     emptyno = true;
                  //   });
                  // } else {
                  //   isBusiness = false;
                  //   await verifyPhone(code + phoneNo);
                  // }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Customer',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add logs to your question.

Comment: just found what was wrong with this code. It was referencing the build cache...

Comment: Anyways, thank you for your consideration and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a solution to my problem. It turns out that there were some cache file which were created and it was referencing those cache.

A `flutter clean` command worked for me and after that code started to work again.